# Sql to get most recent full backup file for a specific database in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup

I need an sql command (dbcc or extended stored procedure?) or something that can be called from a sql server stored procedure to get the most recent full backup file available for a specific database.  The name of the backup file will be placed in a varchar variable that I can use with a RESTORE DATABASE command in the stored procedure.  This procedure will be used to restore from production database to a sandbox/training database, so after the restore completes I need the procedure to continue running so I can make a few modifications to the db.

Comment: After using SQL commands to locate and restore the latest full backup (and sometimes diffs and trns), I recently started using `dbatools` in Powershell, specifically https://docs.dbatools.io/#Restore-DbaDatabase. For example, this command will do everything you need above: `Restore-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance instance -Path "c:\Backup" -DatabaseName "prod_copy" -ReplaceDbNameInFile -IgnoreDiffBackup -IgnoreLogBackup`. What is magic is that if you omit the last 2 args it will locate the full, diffs and trns and restore in them proper order. So if Powershell is an option give this tool a try.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just query [msdb..backupset (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186299.aspx) on the "source" prod server

And a [working example (SQL Rockstar)](http://thomaslarock.com/2011/04/march-madness-sql-server-system-tables-backupset/) too

Edit, 2018

```
SELECT
    bs.database_name,
    bs.backup_start_date,
    bmf.physical_device_name
FROM
    msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf
    JOIN
    msdb.dbo.backupset bs ON bs.media_set_id = bmf.media_set_id
WHERE
    bs.database_name = 'MyDB'
ORDER BY
    bmf.media_set_id DESC;
```

Comment: Sweet, I should be able to get what I need from this query: `select top 1 name from msdb..backupset where name like 'TmsePrd_b%' and type='D' order by name desc`

Comment: I attempted to edit the SQL above but the edit queue is full. In any case, the sql above should include `bs.type` in the where clause so it returns full backups only: `bs.database_name = 'MyDB' and bs.type='D'`

Answer (score 13):

I have a handy script that I use when I restore the most recent backup from a directory to the database you want to restore to.  It is great for refreshing a dev or test box by using a nightly job!

```
/******************************************************
Script: looks at the backup directory and restores the
    most recent backup (bak) file 
    You will have to modify the code
    to match your database names and paths.
    DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION.  It kicks all users off!

Created By:
    Michael F. Berry
Create Date:
    1/15/2014
******************************************************/


--get the last backup file name and path

Declare @FileName varChar(255)
Declare @cmdText varChar(255)
Declare @BKFolder varchar(255)

set @FileName = null
set @cmdText = null
set @BKFolder = '\\MyBackupStorageShare\server\FULL\'


create table #FileList (
FileName varchar(255),
DepthFlag int,
FileFlag int
)


--get all the files and folders in the backup folder and put them in temporary table
insert into #FileList exec xp_dirtree @BKFolder,0,1
--select * from #filelist

--get the latest backup file name
select top 1 @FileName = @BKFolder + FileName from #FileList where Filename like '%.bak' order by filename desc
select @filename


--kick off current users/processes
ALTER DATABASE DBName
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;


--execute the restore
exec('
RESTORE DATABASE [DBNAME] FROM  DISK = ''' + @filename + '''
WITH  MOVE N''DBName_Data'' TO N''E:\SQLData\DBName.mdf'', MOVE N''DBName_Log'' TO N''E:\SQLLogs\DBName_log.ldf'',  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10')


--Let people/processes back in!
ALTER DATABASE DBName
SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
go
```

Answer (score 4):

```
declare @backupfile as Varchar(255)

SELECT TOP 1 @backupfile=mf.physical_device_name from msdb..backupset bk      
join msdb..backupmediafamily mf on bk.media_set_id = mf.media_set_id   
where database_name=N'sourcedatabasename' and bk.type='D' order by  
backup_set_id desc

ALTER DATABASE [databasename] SET  SINGLE_USER  WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE 

RESTORE DATABASE databasename
FROM DISK = @backupfile
WITH MOVE 'datafile' TO 'databasefilepath',
MOVE 'logfilename' TO 'logfilepath', REPLACE

ALTER DATABASE [databasename] SET  MULTI_USER  WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it returns the most recent *full* backup because it includes `bk.type='D'` in the query. If you omit type you may to get a transaction log backup (type=L) or a differential backup (type=I) rather than the "most recent full backup file" which OP asked. Ask me how I know this.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to give an addition to the excellent answer from user2378139.  I often have the need to restore multiple databases from 1 folder, and there will be multiple backup copies for each database in that folder.  I need to get the most recent, and run that on a scheduled task.  Below is my edit/update to make that happen.  There are more temporary tables than i'd like, but haven't figured a better way to do it yet:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TemperedFileList') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TemperedFileList
GO
Declare @FileName varChar(255)
Declare @cmdText varChar(255)
Declare @BKFolder varchar(255)
Declare @DBFolder varchar(255)

set @FileName = null
set @BKFolder = 'E:\SQLBackupFolder\'
set @DBFolder = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.COBRASERVER\MSSQL\DATA\'

declare @FileList table (FileName varchar(255), DepthFlag int, FileFlag int)
--get all the files and folders in the backup folder and put them in temporary table
insert into @FileList exec xp_dirtree @BKFolder,0,1

create table #TemperedFileList (FileName varchar(255),DBName varchar(255))
insert into #TemperedFileList (FileName,DBName) select FileName, SUBSTRING(FileName,0,CHARINDEX('_',FileName)) from @FileList WHERE Filename like '%.bak'

declare @RowCnt int
declare @MaxRows int
declare @tmpFileName varchar(255)
declare @tmpDBName varchar(255)
declare @sql nvarchar(3000)

select @RowCnt = 1

declare @Import table (rownum int IDENTITY (1, 1) Primary key NOT NULL , FileName varchar(255),DBName varchar(255))
insert into @Import (FileName,DBName) SELECT FileName,DBName FROM  (SELECT FileName,DBName,rank() over (partition by DBName order by FileName desc) r FROM  #TemperedFileList ) ilv where r=1

select @MaxRows=count(*) from @Import
while @RowCnt <= @MaxRows
begin
    select @tmpFileName=FileName from @Import where rownum = @RowCnt
    select @tmpDBName=DBName from @Import where rownum = @RowCnt

    set @sql ='ALTER DATABASE ' + @tmpDBName + ' SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE'
    print @sql
    exec(@sql)

    set @sql ='RESTORE DATABASE [' + @tmpDBName + '] FROM  DISK=''' + @BKFolder + @tmpFileName + ''' with FILE=1, MOVE N''' + @tmpDBName + ''' TO N''' + @DBFolder + @tmpDBName + '.mdf'', MOVE N''' + @tmpDBName + '_Log'' TO N''' + @DBFolder + @tmpDBName + '_log.ldf'',  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10'
    print @sql
    exec(@sql)

    set @sql ='ALTER DATABASE ' + @tmpDBName + ' SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE'
    print @sql
    exec(@sql)

    Set @RowCnt = @RowCnt + 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This builds on the above answers.
The Source and Restore Databases are in the script in several places.
That leaves room for a mistake where you fail to correct the database name or restoreDatabase name in one of the places it needs to be.

the following gets the backup file using @user5054734's solution.
the rest is generating SQL and then doing and exec('sql string')
As a template , I used the script MSSQL generated for me using the restore wizard.

Ill also cite @user2378139 for the exec(@sql) approach. I had not done that in a while.
You have to use exec('') because the RESTORE DATABASE command can not use variables embedded in the command. (If it can, please show me how.. pretty sure it can not).

#### An example of the sql I wish to generate looks like this

```
 ALTER DATABASE [testDB] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
RESTORE DATABASE [testDB] FROM  DISK = 'C:\sqlbackups\2023 09 07  10 00 proddb.bak' WITH  FILE = 1 
,MOVE 'prodDB' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\testDB.mdf'
,MOVE 'prodDB_Log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\testDB_log.ldf'
,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5
ALTER DATABASE [testDB] SET MULTI_USER
```

#### Here is the script that produces that SQL and then executes it

Hope it helps someone.

```
USE [master]

declare @backupfile as Varchar(255)
, @dataFolder varchar(255) =   N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\'
, @sourceDatabaseName varchar(100) = 'circupool'
, @restoreDatabaseName varchar(100) ='circupool_testDWH'
 
SELECT TOP 1 @backupfile=mf.physical_device_name from msdb..backupset bk      
join msdb..backupmediafamily mf on bk.media_set_id = mf.media_set_id   
where database_name=N'circupool' and bk.type='D' order by  
backup_set_id desc


 
 

 declare @restoreMDF varchar(200) = concat(@dataFolder,@restoreDatabaseName,'.mdf')
 , @sourceLogFile varchar(200) = concat(@sourceDatabaseName,'_Log')
 , @restoreLog varchar(200) = concat(@dataFolder,@restoreDatabaseName, '_log.ldf')

 select 
   @backupfile [backupfile]
   , @dataFolder [dataFolder]
 , @sourceLogFile [sourceLogFile]
 , @restoreDatabaseName [restoreDBname]
   , @restoreMDF [restoreMDF]
 , @restoreLog [restorelog]
 

 declare @crlf varchar(10) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
 declare @sql varchar(1000) = 
concat('ALTER DATABASE [',@restoreDatabaseName, '] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;', @crlf
,'RESTORE DATABASE [',@restoreDatabaseName, '] FROM  DISK = ''',@backupfile,''' WITH  FILE = 1 ', @crlf  
,',MOVE ''',@sourceDatabaseName, ''' TO ''',@restoreMDF,'''', @crlf
,',MOVE ''',@sourceLogFile,''' TO ''', @restoreLog, '''',  @crlf
,',  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5', @crlf
,'ALTER DATABASE [circupool_testDWH] SET MULTI_USER', @crlf

)
print @sql 
exec( @sql )
```