# Restore database from backup file, where file name matches reg expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, backup

I am doing the below using SQL Server / T-SQL :

```
RESTORE DATABASE UAT
FROM DISK = 'E:\Databases\backup\MY_LIVE_20120720_070001.bak'
WITH REPLACE
```

But I want to be able to use a file location that ignores the numbers in the file name (which represent the date) in my backup file. There will only ever be one `'MY_LIVE_****.bak'` but its number string will change each day.

The goal is to restore my UAT instance from live each week, using the latest backup - of which there will be only file matching that string prefix, but the numbers/date will change each week.

Comment: I think there is already a solution :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101331/sql-to-get-most-recent-full-backup-file-for-a-specific-database-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xp_cmdshell` to do a dir for your file. Note, however, that `xp_cmdshell` is normally disabled for good reasons. Given this is UAT, that may not be an issue.

See here for more http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/dir/

Comment: And how would i use it in a way that would ignore the ever changingnumbers in my filename

Comment: You'd issue the command `dir e:\databases\backup\*.bak` and put the result into your `restore database` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER DATABASE UAT
SET SINGLE_USER WITH
 ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

declare @fileName varchar(56);

SELECT @filename = physical_device_name
FROM msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily
WHERE media_set_id =(
    SELECT TOP 1 media_set_id 
    FROM msdb.dbo.backupset 
    WHERE database_name='MY_LIVE' 
    ORDER BY backup_start_date DESC)

ALTER DATABASE UAT
SET SINGLE_USER WITH
 ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

----Restore Database
RESTORE DATABASE UAT
FROM DISK = @fileName
WITH REPLACE

/*If there is no error in statement before database will be in multiuser
 mode.
 If error occurs please execute following command it will convert
 database in multi user.*/
ALTER DATABASE ASLA_DEV SET MULTI_USER
 GO
```